# Referencing composite index as a foreign key of another table

Tags: python, indexing, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I have a composite index in the department table and want to reference this column (which is unique) as a foreign key in the employee table. The problem is flask migrate does not recognize the composite index?

department table:

```
class Department(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "departments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    dep_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

    employees = db.relationship('Employee',
                                   backref='department',
                                   lazy='dynamic')

    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index('dep_name_id', id, dep_name),
        db.UniqueConstraint(id, dep_name),
    )
```

Employee table:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "employees"

    someinfo = db.Column(db.String(ID_LEN), primary_key=True)
    department_id = db.Column(db.String(500), db.ForeignKey('departments.dep_name_id'))
```

However after running `flask db migrate`, I get the following error (composite index column is not recognized!):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedColumnError: Could not initialize target column for ForeignKey 'deparments.dep_name_id' on table 'employees': 
table 'departments' has no column named 'dep_name_id'
```

Comment: `dep_name_id` is not a column, it is an index, so you can not refer to that in DDL level. Besides, I think you should use only the `department.id` as FK and create whatever you want by relations.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I still want to reference two columns as FK. How should I do that?

Comment: Sorry for my late response,

Answer (score 0):

First make the `deb_name` a PK:

```
class Department(db.Model):
    ...
    dep_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

After that you can create `department_name` FK on `Employee` model:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    ...
    department_id = db.Column(db.String(500), db.ForeignKey('departments.dep_id'))
    department_name = db.Column(db.String(500), db.ForeignKey('departments.dep_name'))
```